# Is it possible to use fancyvrb, eso-pic and TikZ simultaneously?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyvrb, eso-pic

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {Hello};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\fill[blue](0,0)rectangle(1,1);}
\VerbatimInput{tikzducks.sty}
\end{document}
```

It produces the error

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the math
-mode dollar sign. This is incompatible with tikz and its calc library and migh
t cause unrecoverable errors.
```

(The output is OK, but there is this error message.)

The error message disappears when I either comment out the lines

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {Hello};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
```

or if I comment out

```
\VerbatimInput{tikzducks.sty}
```

My conclusion (perhaps wrong) is that there is a delicate interference between all three of the packages fancyvrb, eso-pic and TikZ, which is perhaps why I could not find any discussion of this here.

**QUESTION**: Is there a way to cure this?

Comment: `\VerbatimInput[codes={\catcode`\$=3}]` could work (if ducks don't love money) :-)

Comment: it's \catcode`\

Comment: @touhami no that would make `$` a math shift character so would break the verbatim reading of the file if it has a `$` anywhere.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so ducks love money i'll delete all comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is here a false positive: Even if the picture would use `$`, as they are already tokenized they would work fine. The check from tikz doesn't prevent following errors as it doesn't reset the catcode.  I would redefine the tikz command that checks the catcode of the `$` either to relax or to a warning. Imho this is quite enough.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
% or \let\tikz@ensure@dollar@catcode\relax
\def\tikz@ensure@dollar@catcode{%
  \ifnum\catcode`\$=3 %
  \else
    \pgfutil@packagewarning{tikz}{Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the
      math-mode dollar sign. This is incompatible with tikz and its calc
      library and might cause unrecoverable errors}%
    % only show warning once:
    \global\let\tikz@ensure@dollar@catcode=\relax
  \fi
}%

\makeatother
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {Hello};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\fill[blue](0,0)rectangle(1,1);}
\VerbatimInput{tikzducks.sty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is nice, but what happens if some package really does crazy things to $ sign? Or are you saying that, regardless of what other packages are doing, there will never be a problem, and the error message issued by Ti*k*Z is just superfluous?

Comment: If a package does crazy things to $ you will get problems/errors if you use the $-syntax inside the tikz code. But the error from tikz doesn't prevent this, it is only a bit earlier and perhaps easier to understand. Imho its benefits don't compensate the annoying false positives.

Answer (score 6):

The verbatim settings are not being reset in the page head overlay from `eso-pic` as a workaround you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
    \catcode`$=3 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {Hello};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}

\tikz{\fill[blue](0,0)rectangle(1,1);}
\VerbatimInput{tikzducks.sty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The standard page header/footer code doesn't reset catcodes. If you do e.g. `\def\@oddfoot{\tikz\draw (0,0);}`  or `\lhead{\tikz{\fill[blue](0,0)rectangle(1,1);}}`  with fancyhdr you get the same error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes sorry I'll amend. Of course the test in tikz doesn't do anything useful either since the tikz has already been tokenized.

Comment: Yes, probably a global `\let\tikz@ensure@dollar@catcode\relax` is the best solution. After all the test doesn't do much more than warn that one perhaps get a problem and imho the false positive is more annoying than a failing tikz.